# How can I make this tick without Thread.Sleep?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

So I'm just starting to learn events and I've made a `PeriodicTick` class that inherits from a `Tick` class that I've written. Now I think it works okay, but I think I read earlier that it's always a bad idea to use `Thread.Sleep()` now I'm using it in a seperate task so there shouldn't be any problems with parallelization.

Nevertheless, my question is, in this case is it fine to use `Thread.Sleep()` and if not is there any other simple solution for me to achieve the same thing?

EDIT: Right! Here's the code..

```
class Tick
{
    #region Fields & Properties

    public delegate void TickHandler();
    static int ctr = new int();
    public readonly int ID;
    public event TickHandler OnTick;
    public bool isActive;

    #endregion

    public Tick()
    {
        ID = ctr++;
    }
    public virtual void Start()
    {
        OnTick();
    }
}
class PeriodicTick : Tick
{
    int tickTimer;
    public Predicate<PeriodicTick> TickUntil { get; set; }

    public PeriodicTick(int tickTimer, Predicate<PeriodicTick> tickUntil)
    {
        this.tickTimer = tickTimer;
        TickUntil = tickUntil;
    }
    public override void Start()
    {
        Task TickTimer = Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () => 
            {
                while (TickUntil.Invoke(this))
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(tickTimer);
                    base.Start();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There are several different types of Timers out there.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? If you want something to happen periodically (every second, every 13 minutes, etc.), then you want a timer. A good overview of timers is [Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

Comment: The basic concept of sleep, or better still, waiting on a cancellable token is fine in a background thread. Sleep is mostly just evil on the GUI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET 4.5 introduced Task.Delay(Int32), that would be the correct way to handle delays in Tasks.

[thread-sleep-vs-task-delay](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21177.visual-c-thread-sleep-vs-task-delay.aspx)

Comment: You can also use `TaskEx.Delay` in the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` nuget package to use this in .NET 4.0.